# Finding the particular solution of non homogeneous differential equation

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus

Can someone find the particular solution, the complementary solution is not required. What general form to assume for $y_{p}$?
\begin{align*}
y'' + y' = 8\cos(2x) - 4\sin(x)
\end{align*}

Comment: Integrate once, apply the integrating factor and integrate again.

Comment: You need to know the complementary solution in order to know the correct form for $y_p$.

Comment: And, by the way, [How to ask a homework question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1803/how-to-ask-a-homework-question).

Comment: @user1337 That's an interesting approach. Could you demonstrate it?

Comment: @Allawonder, sure! I will post my solution.

Answer (score 0):

$$y'' + y' = 8\cos(2x) - 4\sin(x)$$
For the particular solution try :
$$y_p=A\cos (2x)+B\sin(2x)+C\cos x+ D \sin x$$
Since the solution to the homogeneous equation is:
$$y_h=c_1+c_2 e^{-x}$$

---

You can use also:
$$y'_p=A\cos (2x)+B\sin(2x)+C\cos x+ D \sin x$$
And integrate $y'_p$.

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align}
 y_{p}  &=  \frac{1}{D^2+D} (8\cos2x-4\sin x)\\
&= \ \frac{1}{D^2+D} 8\cos2x - \frac{1}{D^2+D} 4\sin x\\ 
&= \ 8\frac{1}{-4+D}\cos2x -  4\frac{1}{-1+D}\sin x \\
&= \ 8\frac{D+4}{D^2-16}\cos2x -  4\frac{D+1}{D^2-1}\sin x\\
&= \ 8\frac{D+4}{-20}\cos2x -  4\frac{D+1}{-2}\sin x\\
&= \ -\frac{2}{5}(D+4)\cos2x +  2(D+1)\sin x\\
&= \ -\frac{2}{5}(-2\sin2x+4\cos2x) +  2(\cos x+\sin x)  \\ 
&= \ \frac{4}{5}(\sin2x-2\cos2x)+ 2(\sin x+\cos x)
\end{align}

Comment: @letsShareKnowlede  if my answer was helpful , please accept my answer.......

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

Integrating both sides, one has that
\begin{align*}
y'' + y' = 8\cos(2x) - 4\sin(x) \Longleftrightarrow y' + y = 4\sin(2x) + 4\cos(x) + c
\end{align*}
Multiplying both sides by $e^{x}$, we have that
\begin{align*}
e^{x}y' + e^{x}y = e^{x}(4\sin(2x) + 4\cos(x) + c) & \Longleftrightarrow (e^{x}y)' = e^{x}(4\sin(2x) + 4\cos(x) + c)\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow e^{x}y = \int e^{x}(4\sin(2x) + 4\cos(x) + c)\mathrm{d}x + d\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow y(x) = c + de^{-x} + e^{-x}\int e^{x}(4\sin(2x) + 4\cos(x))\mathrm{d}x
\end{align*}

Now it just remains to solve the last integral, which should not be difficult.